# jQuery: function to check if array is multidimentional

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I just wanted to know if anyone knew of a simple function to check if a given array is multidimensional and, if possible, also see how many dimensions it has.

Here is a sample array:

```
{"name":"Tiradentes","id":"234534gfgdgd4y5hy","areas":{{"name":"Apucarana", "id":"fh4oth98f894nf89h4"},{etc..., etc....}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite (I suppose) simple function counting dimensions BOTH in Arrays and array-like Objects (like in your case):

```
function countDimensions(arr)
{
  if (! (arr && typeof arr === 'object') ) {
    return 0;
  }
  var maxCount = Math.max.apply(null, $.map(arr, function(n) {
    return countDimensions(n);
  }));
  return 1 + (isFinite(maxCount) ? maxCount : 0);
}
```

jQuery is used, as 0) it's mentioned in tags, 1) naive checking for Array with `instanceof Array` can lead to tricky results in multiframe apps, 2) `$.map` is a convenient shortcut for moving through all the *array* values.

It can be rewritten in plain JS, of course, but it won't be as compact. )

Had to use `isFinite` check, as `protomax`-ing an empty array gives `-Infinite`.

Comment: Just a quick question. I just used it on my array which is 2-dimensional and it returned 1. Does it start at 0?

Comment: Can you give an example of your array?

Comment: So, I am getting my array from an $.ajax call that is posting to a PHP page and returning an json array. The array is more or less a follows: {"name":"Tiradentes","id":"234534gfgdgd4y5hy",{{"name":"Apucarana", "id":"fh4oth98f894nf89h4"},{etc..., etc....}}}

Comment: Ah, as I suspected. What you got from PHP is not an Array: it's an Object. You can still use this function (with the update), but these - Arrays and Objects - are quite different beasts.

Comment: Ahhhh... Thanks! I figured it was a json **array**

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
var dims = 0;
function getArrayDimensions(arr) {
 if(typeof(arr) != 'array') return false;
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if(typeof(arr[i]) == 'array') dims++;
   dims += getArrayDimensions(arr[i]);
 }
 return dims;
}
```

Comment: Ouch, no! Has anyone who upvoted this read the code or tried it out? Apparently not, it is ridden by mistakes.

Comment: Hint: `typeof []` => `'object'`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays are not really multi-dimensional, they are lists that can consist of different data types. So you only can determine the depth of an array by testing how often your array contains another array:

```
var isArray = Array.isArray || function(a) {
    return a instanceof Array || Object.prototype.toString.call(a) == "[object Array]";
};

function getDepth(o) {
    for (var i=0; isArray(o); o=o[0])
        i++;
    return i;
}
```

A more restrictive implementation would count the levels on which *all* slots of the array contain other arrays, instead of only inspecting the first one. Results would differ for `[[], 0]` for example.

```
function getDepth(o) {
    if (!isArray(o))
        return 0;
    return 1 + (o.length && Math.min.apply(null, o.map(getDepth)));
}
```